# Post review with google maps api?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

Is it possible to post a review through the google-maps-api?

The only answer I've found was that in 2011 it wasn't possible but planned to be implemented.

I don't find anything corresponding in the documentation. Not even that it isn't possible.

Specifically I want to post a review via an Android App.

Comment: there is nothing in the api that allows you to do reviews

Answer (score 0):

The answer you were looking for is on Google Places Issue tracker [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3506). As of April 2016 it still hasn't been developed. Star the Google places issue for further updates.